# Conditional format rules for Google Sheets double values

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting, textjoin

What I'm trying to achieve is whenever a value on a sheet is already written on another sheet it's background color should change.

The range where it should check whether the value is already existing is: B2:AF120
The range from the other sheet where values already exist is: Sheet2!G3:Q58

The custom formula I've tried is:

```
=match(B2:AF120,indirect("Teams!G3:Q58"),0)
```

You can see the entire thing on the image below.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVPeh.png]

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: @player0 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_rNAqfVO0nTdUb4To59KvraxWA-ZmeFxUVvBQjBGRZQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=REGEXMATCH(B2, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, INDIRECT("Sheet2!G3:Q")))
```

and the exact match would be:

```
=REGEXMATCH(B2, "^"&TEXTJOIN("$|^", 1, INDIRECT("Sheet2!G3:Q"))&"$")
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that looks way too confusing for me ^^'

Comment: do check if the sheet names are same Sheet2<>Teams